# PouchDB/CouchDB Versioning for audit trail

Tags: couchdb, versioning, pouchdb, audit-trail

I am using PouchDB/CouchDB for my hybrid ionic mobile app. Now i want to implement audit trail for the same. This link [Versioning using storing versions as attachment in the same document](http://web.archive.org/web/20101203010111/http://jchrisa.net/drl/_design/sofa/_list/post/post-page?startkey=%5B%22Versioning-docs-in-CouchDB%22%5D) suggests to store versions of the document as attachment of the same document. I have few queries regarding this:

Is the approach specific to jquery.couch.js as when i try to implement in my mobile app as:  in couchdb i have a doc(say _id=1) having its versions as attachments. Now when i sync this doc on my mobile device (using pouch sync), i fetch the doc without its attachments(its versions), then modify this document and in attachment i add the previous revision and then sync.. Now since its revision no is greatest, it goes in couchdb and this latest document (_id=1) has attachment which only shows latest version...

When i do sync from couchdb to pouchdb, do i need to fetch this doc(_id=1)with its attachments (which contains all revisions)? If yes, then in this case i will be syncing these attachments unnecessarily which will be overhead....
Then in this case should i go with
[storing versions in separate document apparoach?](https://blog.couchbase.com/how-implement-document-versioning-couchbase)

Comment: your first link is broken

Answer (score 1):

couch/pouch already keeps an audit log of changes in the revisions. You can access the changes using the _changes endpoint and display it when needed. (storing it as an attachment seems to be duplicating the existing data)

Pouch: https://pouchdb.com/api.html#changes

Couch: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/database/changes.html